# Does the PH in your mouth affect taste?

Tags: yogurt

I’ve eaten plain whole-milk yogurt every day for over 10 yrs.  One 32 oz tub of the brand name I buy can taste sweet & mild one day; sour & acidic the next...or vice versa.

I’ve complained to yogurt makers so many times; even sending batch info & pics...and they’ve been so nice...thanking me & sending me coupons for free yogurt.

Now, however, I honestly think the perception of different tastes has to do with the changing chemistry in my mouth or on my tongue. Eating something sweet OR savory OR salty...that does NOT seem to matter. It’s just sour some days; sweet the next.

What’s going on??

Comment: pH of the mouth should affect the taste of the first scoop or so, but after that pH of your mouth becomes pH of yogurt.

Comment: Are you double-dipping or transferring the part you're going to eat into a smaller container using a clean spoon each time?

Comment: 3650 straight days of yogurt?!?

Comment: The reversal is interesting - changes in an open container, even within the use-by date, would be less surprising, particularly if it has live cultures.

Comment: BTW, I can tell that for me, the taste of beer is *heavily* affected by my thoughts and mood. It can flip from sip to sip depending on memories and thoughts of the moment. For such a yogurt aficionado as OP, it might be possible similar effect occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have not expericed the same thing with products other than yoghurt. It is difficult to standardize the taste and consistency of yoghurt despite of climate controlled manufacturing facilities because there are numerous factors other than just temperature. Also, the milk is not always the same despite of homogenization process.

In other words, it's not your mouth, it's the product which comes out different every time. It is also the case with artisan wines.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. The OP is asking about the same container used for more than one day - not different containers or yogurts purchased at different times.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Yes Cindy. You are right. One night, Dannon whole milk plain is simple, mild & uncomplicated to my taste buds. The next night, a serving from the same tub tastes so tangy, my glands retract like a sea anemone. I’ve learned not to toss it, or  contact Dannon quality control like I used to. I just wait & try it again the next night (from the same 32 oz tub that tasted acidic the night before)...& now it’s back to tasting mild, simple & creamy. It’s GOTTA be something having to do with me & the chemistry in my mouth! It only happens with yogurt. I just can’t find anyone who can explain it.